# While doing mv from one disk partition to another disk partition, my files are deleted, is there any way i can retrieve it?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, backup, mv

I mounted **/backup** partition by adding another disk than ran a command in **/backup1** directory which is the part of root partition which belongs to old disk.

I ran this command - `mv * /backup/`

Now, my all files in /backup1 are gone. Also, /backup directory is also empty.

What did id do wrong?

Can I retrieve it?

Comment: It doesn't look like you did anything wrong. So this is a bit odd. That said it _is_ possible to recover deleted files. The data is still there... it's just been marked as usable space. Which is why you should shut your system down asap and use another computer to download a live CD with data recovery software. Active@ makes some pretty good tools for this.

Comment: I just saw a similar post to this in the last month.  This appears to be a bug in linux where it deletes the source without verifying the copy (but unsure.. DONT ATTACK ME).  I would suggest to ANYONE reading this.  COPY (don't move) files, then delete them yourself when going between volumes.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas, please cite a source, a link to a bug report or an example.

Comment: @Eduardo_Trápani , I can't find the post and I looked hard for it.  They guy wasn't asking about mv.. he was asking how to get his files back after the operation described above.. that makes this hard to search for.  ***I am happy to delete the comment*** but I would suggest cp instead of mv for any important data (since there really is no such thing as mv.. more like copy then delete).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas This is not so simple. When you `mv` within a single filesystem, `mv` is safer, faster and lot less resource hungry than copy+delete. Certainly not equivalent. "There is no such thing as `mv`" is false. I can agree with your suggestion when it comes to moving *between* filesystems though.

Comment: Since `/backup` is a mount point, it is either a file system or an empty directory when nothing is mounted. So the first thing to do is `df /backup` to check if it corresponds to a mounted  file system. if you are lucky, the filesystem got unmounted after you moved the files and will be recoverable if you re-mount the file system.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see in your post, that's the expected behaviour:

```
$ cd /backup
$ mv * /backup1
```

That will `mv`, and that means **move** all files from their original location `/backup` to the new location `/backup1`.